# Building a docker passing arguments at command line or via the docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm new to the Dockerisation. My goal is to setup a Ruby container to develop a website.
My first challenge is having a persistent working directory on the local host available in the container, so that container can be used to develop and run, but host to "save" and git whenever required.

I thought the first thing to do is having both a local group and user in the container that are equal to my host.
My first lines of the docker file looks like the below:

```
ARG USER_ID
ARG GROUP_ID

FROM ruby

RUN addgroup --gid $GROUP_ID user
RUN adduser --disabled-password --gecos '' --uid $USER_ID --gid $GROUP_ID user
```

However, when I try to build my image using the docker-compose build with args in the file or at command line, I still receive the same error `The command '/bin/sh -c addgroup --gid $GROUP_ID user' returned a non-zero code: 1`.
Inspecting the prompt it seems like my arguments are not passed back to the build process for some reason, but I don't understand why (if I hard code values, I can run past this problem).

My command line looks like: `env USER_ID=${UID} GROUP_ID=${GID} docker-compose build` while the compose file is as below (first lines):

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  ruby_dev:
    build: # "context" and "dockerfile" fields have to be under "build"
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Ruby
      args:
        USER_ID: 1000
        GROUP_ID: 1000
    # command: ....
```

Regrettably other questions or examples I looked at are not pointing me to the right direction. Any help for understanding my error?

Comment: Your `from` clears the previous args, Declare them right after it. See https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#scope. Moreover, what your are doing is basically useless IMO. You can run the container (or exec a command inside it) as any arbitrary user passing the `-u user[id]:group[id]` parameter to the command line.

Comment: As a quickndirty example, given you have an `app` folder in the current dir containing your sources and you just want to run a ruby container for development to execute them as your current userid and have the sources available in `/app` in the container as a bind mount from your host folder, you could simply issue `docker run -it --name my_rb -v $(pwd)/app:/app -u $(id -u):$(id -g) ruby bash` (to be adapted to your real need).

Comment: You might find a version manager like [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) easier to use for day-to-day development.  This will give you a specific Ruby version, and you can either use rbenv-gemset or Bundler's native functionality to get an isolated package set per application, without having to navigate Docker's isolation features.  Hard-coding a host user ID into an image isn't usually a best practice.

Comment: @DavidMaze thanks, but apparently Ruby doesn't want to compile on my Linux machine for whatever reason. So the container is my last attempt in trying to get access my personal website and continue to use it

Comment: @Zeitounator thanks for the hints. I read that ARG have to be setup before the FROM. Am I misread this? Your second docker command, how can the container know about my local user if that doesn't exist? I'm trying to understand this bit here `-u $(id -u):$(id -g)`

Comment: The user does not have to exist, just try it. The only drawback is that `id -a` for example will only return a userid and not a user name. Regarding args: you can declare them before `from` to use them inside the from clause itself (e.g. for image name or tag). But as stated in the linked doc: `An ARG instruction goes out of scope at the end of the build stage where it was defined. To use an arg in multiple stages, each stage must include the ARG instruction.` You can consider the args on top of your file as stage 0 args which go out of scope as soon as you declare the next (i.e. first) stage.

Comment: @Zeitounator going to try in a moment to understand. Re the ARG going out of scope, well, that was excpected, but in fact my goal initally was to build the container/image adding both the users and the group. Once the image would have been prepared, I would have not expected that Argument to be used anymore, but the user to be in place at every `docker run` call.